# PS0224 No message text found! error after installing .net 4.5.2

Tags: .net, postsharp

I have recently installed the .net 4.5.2 dev pack and cannot compile a few .net 4.0 projects that implement postsharp 4.1.13 aspects. The relevant items in the output windows after clean and build are

> : message PS0220: PostSharp needs to generate binding maps for the
> selected platform. This could take a while. The result will be cached
> and the next build will be faster.
>
> : postsharp error PS0224: [PS0224].> No message text found!.

4.5.2 Projects that do and do not use post sharp 4.1.17 can compile correctly.

We have removed the .13 nuget package from the projects and added the .17 version, and that seems to have corrected the problem, but that revision increment comes with its own postsharp versioning issues we would like to avoid.

Does anyone have an idea of how to determine what may be causing this or how to go about correcting it and remaining on version .13?

Comment: What kind of versioning issues would you like to avoid by keeping 4.1.13?

Comment: @JakubLinhart part of our work is to build extensible frameworks that other developers in our company (and ourselves) use.  If our framework is built to use .13, then all dll extensions or implementers are essentially locked into .13. If we update to .17, then we force all callers to update.

Answer (score 0):

PS0224 means that PostSharp could not access a file while generating binding maps for the current compilation. All of these files are stored in `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\BindingMaps` and the most likely problem is that the user under which PostSharp is running does not have write access to this directory.

Since you have installed .NET 4.5.2, which is an in-place upgrade, PostSharp needed to generate new binding maps as it running on a different version of .NET.

Indeed there was a merge issue in our codebase sometime ago and the message text was not included in this version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some of us run VS "as adminstrator" and were getting the same error. I do have that folder in my local, and it has a 4.5.2 subfolder with a bunch of assemblymap files, but my bindingmap folder has different content from others's folders. Do you know what the ideal folder structure looks like so we can continue this inspection?

Comment: Everything should be in `BindingMaps\v1`. Next level is target framework (of the compiled assembly). In this level you will have `.AssemblyMaps` file and `.AssemblyMap` file for each referenced target. Next level is for native framework (version of .NET used when running PostSharp). Since this is a cache and is created lazily, different machines may have different content. We use a global Mutex for synchronization if possible. You can always delete the folder and PostSharp should recreate it - if it is able. Since 4.1.13 is missing the error message we cannot be sure which file it is.